# If a cat hasn't played much for the last couple of days, and has spent of most of his time sleeping -- should one be worried?

Tags: cats, health

Observations:

1. cat has only played once, half-heartedly, each day, for the last two days
2. cat still is quite social
3. cat was neutered a little more than a month ago
4. cat has spent much of its "free time" sleeping
5. cat has been eating well, and defecating well
6. cat has been found to be lactose tolerant, and thus gets a bit of milk each day as a treat

Any cause for concern?

Comment: As long as the cat eats and allows you touching it, I wouldn't be worried too much. Cat's obviously can't talk, but you can see it when they feel uneasy or sick. From your list points 2 and 5 are probably the most important ones telling you that everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cats do spend less time actively playing as they get older. You could try encouraging them with some new and/or interactive toys. Different cats respond to different things - one of mine still loves chasing the laser pointer dot, especially when I run it across the couch so she can dive at ti full speed and just bounce when it escapes, the other has no interest in the "red bug" but really likes wrestling with length of thick string. One of them will bring me a small  ball to throw for her. They both like hunting the feather wand.

Cats do spend less time actively playing as they become adults. Play is partly about learning what they can do, and once they get that figured out they don't need to spend as much time practicing or exploring.  Again, giving them something new to investigate, or getting involved in playing with them, may be more interesting for them.

But in general, adult cats are very efficient creatures.  When nothing needs to be done, they sleep... or find someplace to sit and watch birds or humans or other oddities.

Comment: I'd expand a bit: In my experience, older cats tend to play less often *on their own*, but in general they won't say 'no' to some potential prey, like the mentioned laserpointer, leafs, etc.

Comment: @Mario: true, but what "prey" is interesting depends on the cat. Some love a particular toy, others will bat at it a few times and then look up as if to say "ok, human, have I amused you enough? " Hence my suggestion that finding the _right _ toy can make a difference.